# SSL between Java and SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a backend written in jJva(Maven) in ubuntu OS and a frontend written with react native. My database is SQL Server that it is in windows server.

I have worked with this structure and don't have problem.

But now I have a problem when my backend want to connect to SQL Server.

This is my code

```
package com.mavenproject3.resources;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Path("javaee8")
public class JavaEE8Resource {

    private Connection connection = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    @GET
    public Response ping(){
         String connectionUrl =  "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.38:1433;databaseName=DB3;user=sa;password=38601122MajId"; 
        try {
            Class.forName(classForName);
            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                connection = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connection = null;
        }
        return Response
                .ok("successfully connect to DB")
                .build();
    }
}
```

When this function is called in the browser I have this problem

```
  StandardWrapperValve[com.mavenproject3.JAXRSConfiguration]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.mavenproject3.JAXRSConfiguration threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:708)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:583)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1794)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2558)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2067)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:825)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.mavenproject3.resources.JavaEE8Resource.ping(JavaEE8Resource.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
```

Thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

When examining the error dump we can see the exception thrown:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V

key here is -> NoSuchMethodError

This would lead me to believe a version change has resulted in a function that is no longer supported.

One place i would start is to check all the changes that may have interfered with the existing code base.

I will look further into this as i have time but i suspect this may be related to a change within the sql or within Ubuntu packages it-self.

I had an interesting break in functionality with my robotics project after updating my data base version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is ... everything was fine at the time of the development. It happened suddenly

Comment: Do you mean to change the mssql version?

Comment: Well its possible you updated your OS using apt-get upgrade which then updated the version from the version you originally used. Its possible the newer version handles the ssl handshake differently which would explain the exception.